# How to get confidence with opencv3 LBPHFaceRecognizer and python3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I see example where the predict() returns (id, confidence) but when I try it with cv2 and python3 I get error saying `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

```
recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
recognizer.load('trained.yml')

# This throws the error
name_id, confidence = recognizer.predict(frame) 
# This runs
name_id = recognizer.predict(frame)
```

Is there any other way of getting the confidence?

Answer (score 0):

```
prediction = model.predict(face_resize)
cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
print prediction

if prediction[1]>50 and prediction[1]<85:
cv2.putText(frame,
  '%s - %.0f' % (names[prediction[0]],prediction[1]),
  (x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 255, 0))                   
else:
cv2.putText(frame,
  'Unknown',
  (x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1,(0, 0, 255))
```

Comment: where's the confidence?

Comment: I am using this in my code and I am getting confidence at side of the name.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sk2rzJYGhqE you can check this link, see while recognizing it shows confidence with the name.

Comment: are you using python3 ?

Comment: No I'm using 2.7.10  and Opencv2.4.10

Comment: I want to get confidence using python3 and opencv3

Comment: Can you show the output  of you'r program (screenshot), have you seen the  video if so, do you want the confidence as shown in the video?